# Syntax error for "with open(file, 'r+'):"

Tags: python

I have a bunch of .csh in a directory and I want to open them one by one, search for "//" and replace it with "/" with a python script. How do I do that?

I tried:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".csh"):
        with open(file, 'r+'):
            data = file.read().replace("//", "/")
            f.write(data)
            f.close()
```

But it gives me:

```
File "script.py", line 4
    with open(file, 'r+'):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I edited the question and posted what I've tried

Comment: why -2? I think it is a fair question...

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to,

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if file.endswith(".csh"):
        with open(file, 'r+') as f:
            data = f.read()
            f.seek(0)

        with open(file, 'w+') as w:
            dat = data.replace("//", "/")
            w.write(dat)
```

Comment: remove the `f.close()`  line because is not necessary when using the `with` context manager.

Comment: It is still gives me the syntax error...

I using 4 spaces as indentation and tried also copying the code as you've put here

Comment: File "script.py", line 4
    with open(file, 'r+'):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

(it points to the end of "open")

Comment: `with open(file, 'r+') as f:`, you forget to add `as f`

Comment: It ran now, but no change in the file whatsoever. 
What should be like this: 

`/home/software/gate6.1/gate/bin/Linux-g++/Gate /gridware/workdir/ammonteiro/.Gate/test2/test210.mac`
stayed: 
`/home/software/gate6.1/gate/bin/Linux-g++/Gate /gridware/workdir/ammonteiro/.Gate//test2//test210.mac`

Comment: The program only changes the name of the file or change its content?

Comment: it changes the file contents, not the name.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old version of Python. [The `with` statement was introduced in Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement), where it had to be enabled via

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

It is best to upgrade to 2.7, if you need to stay in the 2.x line, or 3.4.

Note that you also need to change your code according the answer by Avinash Raj, capturing the file object in a variable via `as f`. `file.read()` will not work because `file` continues to be the file name string.

Comment: @tripleee No it isn't, the `as ...` part is optional as far as syntax goes. Though, I'll expand my answer a bit.

Comment: yes it turns out I have 2.4.3 version I will update and post here if it worked. thank you Janne!

Comment: It ran now, but no change in the file whatsoever.

What should be like this:

`/home/software/gate6.1/gate/bin/Linux-g++/Gate /gridware/workdir/ammonteiro/.Gate/test2/test210.mac`

stayed

`/home/software/gate6.1/gate/bin/Linux-g++/Gate /gridware/workdir/ammonteiro/.Gate//test2//test210.mac`

Comment: The program only changes the name of the file or change its content?